# How to group by month in LINQ query?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datetime, group-by

I made this LINQ query

```
var db = new DataEntities();
var records = db.Table_1.GroupBy(x => x.date).tolist();
```

where Table_1 columns of are of type

```
ColumnName       dataType

id               numeric
date             datetime
```

Records in table_1:

```
1          3/May/2013
2          4/Apr/2013
3          7/May/2013
```

i want to groupby all records of Table_1 according to Months like

```
var records = db.Table_1.GroupBy(x => x.date.Month);
```

is there any way to do this?

Comment: What error do you get? And what are you using, Entity Framework or LINQ-to-SQL?

Comment: its not giving me option of x.date.month

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using *Entity Framework* you can use the [SqlFunctions.DatePart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487171.aspx)

```
.GroupBy(x => SqlFunctions.DatePart("m", x.date))
```

Comment: its not giving me SqlFunctions.DatePart  is there is any refernce to add

Answer (score 1):

i find the right answer this also helps you......

```
  System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo DFI=new System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo();
            var InvoiceDetailMonthwise = (from t in clsGlobalObjectRefrances.SchoolSoulController.Stt.ssspAccInvoiceBook(clsSchoolSoulObjects.OAcdSchoolInfo.SchoolId,clsSchoolSoulObjects.OAcdSchoolInfo.CurrentActiveSessionId )
                                          group t by new { t.VDate.Value.Month} 
                                              into grp
                                              select new lcclsInvoiceBook
                                              {
                                                  Month=DFI.GetMonthName( grp.Key.Month).ToString(),
                                                  Debit = grp.Sum(t => t.DebitAmount) > 0 ? 0 : -(grp.Sum(t => t.DebitAmount)),
                                                  Credit = grp.Sum(t => t.CreditAmount ) > 0 ? (grp.Sum(t => t.CreditAmount )) : 0,

                                              }).ToList();



            dgvInvoiceBook.DataSource = InvoiceDetailMonthwise;
```